# Getting data from multiple files at the same time

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Lets say I have 3 txt files with contents as followed:

```
1.txt

A
B
C

2.txt

D
E
F

3.txt

G
H
I
```

What I'd like to do is to read the same line from each of them like this:

```
A D G
B E H
C F I
```

How can it be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want strings (would be a weird requirement for PowerShell, though) and each file has the same number of lines:

```
$1,$2,$3 = 1..3 | ForEach-Object { Get-Content $_.txt }
0..($1.Count) | ForEach-Object {
  $1[$_], $2[$_], $3[$_] -join ' '
}
```

Comment: I see I have much to learn ahead of me...
Is there a name for this method?
What does $_ represent?

Comment: `$_` is an automatic variable, representing the current object in many scriptblocks, e.g. in the scriptblock for `ForEach-Object` and other cmdlets.

Comment: Well it was a good try then. I'm afraid it doesnt work.
I get all bunch of errors out of it :-\
Even the first line doesnt run.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
$1,$2,$3 = 1..3|%{,(get-content "$_.txt")}
$1 | % {$i=0} {$_, $2[$i], $3[$i++] -join ' '}
```

Comment: Updated.  Try it now.